# Custom map in Google Map?

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, tiles

On a website I see they use Google Map, but the map looks special and is different from other Google Maps I saw. Is that special-looking map provided by Google Maps or made by the website themselves?

I checked "My Maps" on Google Maps and didn't find related options.

[A website with special-looking Google Map tiles](http://bit.ly/dikAT2)

Comment: As you can See the map is by google. But The website have used JS,CSS,HTML(Design),  Maps and other technology to make a good mapping experience.

Comment: @ErBnAcharya. Is their map provided by Google Maps as well? Or they created it and embedded it?

Comment: It is the map provided by google map, You can do many thing with V3 api of Google map. The credits goes to idea and implementation with help of  Google maps API..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called Styled Maps. See the documentation and examples here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling?hl=en

Comment: Yes! That's what I'm looking for.